# I can't make a right legend by d3.js

Tags: d3.js, legend

### This is my result belowing:

[image: results]

### But what I want is put every bars together like this:

[image]

### And follow the belowing is my major code about legend:

[image]

Comment: please dont put code screenshots provide afiddle

Comment: Please, don't paste a picture of the code, paste the code itself.

Comment: sorry for that. [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zs87oua5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most traditional (and versatile) way for creating such legends among D3 community is using `<text>` and `<rect>` SVG elements (which you can position the way you want). But once you're using HTML `<li>`, try one of these two approaches in your CSS:

```
li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Or

```
li {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: by tthe way, do you know how to make the bar longer?

Comment: Make the text longer (with some spaces).

Comment: Do you have better way just adjust the bar only? Follow the above example, they had longer bar.

Comment: Yes, but not with your code: your bars follow the lenght of your `<li>` (better explaining: your bars are top borders of your texts). So, the simplest way is adding white spaces to the text

Comment: uh...I mean I follow [this](http://eyeseast.github.io/visible-data/2013/08/27/responsive-legends-with-d3/) add code about legend. I should get the same results with the same code.